# JQuery Show Alert if page is idle for x seconds - but only do it once

Tags: jquery

I've seen various topics on how to show an alert or popup when there is no activity on a web page.

But none of the examples actually do what I'd like to do.

Load the web page. If at any point there is a 5 second idle period show an alert.
Once the user interacts with the page ( clears the alert, moves the mouse etc ) the alert clears and thats it.  I don't want it to repeat every 5 seconds of idle time.

I've been looking at:
https://github.com/thorst/jquery-idletimer which seems to do what I want and has a `destroy` option.

```
// stop the timer, removes data, removes event bindings
// to come back from this you will need to instantiate again
// returns: jQuery
$( document ).idleTimer("destroy");
```

But I'm struggling to get it to stop once there is activity is resumed.

There is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/njp70kqp/1/)** here that shows what I mean.

When the page load it shows as `active` don't do anything for 2 seconds and it goes `idle`. Move the mouse again and it goes `active` and at that point the timer should be disabled as I don't want any more idle checking.

Can any one suggest how I can do this ?

** **UPDATE** **

Adding the following to the `active.idleTimer` function works but only on the second period of inactivity. New **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/njp70kqp/2/)**

```
$( document ).idleTimer("active");
$( document ).idleTimer("destroy");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've update your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aminur/njp70kqp/4/), here i've used a flag variable to mark whether it has already been shown the idle message.

```
var idleFlag;
  $(document).on("idle.idleTimer", function(event, elem, obj) {
    if (!idleFlag) {
      idleFlag = true;
      $("#state").html("idle");
    }
  });
```